# I'm having trouble with alexa parsing requests for my skill

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

When I ask something the request is not being parsed well.  It's as if alexa is dumb. :-)

Here is my custom interaction model ...

```
        {
      "name": "CommandIntent",
      "slots": [
        {
          "name": "room",
          "type": "roomSlot"
        },
        {
          "name": "temp",
          "type": "AMAZON.NUMBER"
        },
        {
          "name": "verb",
          "type": "verbSlot"
        }
      ],
      "samples": [
        "turn {verb} in {room}",
        "set {room} to {temp}"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "types": [
    {
      "name":"verbSlot",
      "values": [
        "up",
        "down",
        "heat",
        "heater",
        "cool",
        "AC",
        "off"
      ]
    },
    {
      "name":"roomSlot",
      "values": [
        "living",
        "master",
        "guest"
      ]
    }
 ]
```

When I say "ask air set living to 73" it works with {room:living, temp:73}.

But when I say "ask air turn heater in master" it doesn't work. The result is wrong, I only get {room:heater} and heater isn't even a room.

Most samples and slots don't work for me. Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I've figured this out.  I was expecting it to recognize different actions in one intent.  When I created more intents with narrower meanings everything worked.